# VLANs allowed vs VLANs active -- cannot pull DHCP over WiFi

Tags: dhcp, cisco-wireless

I am trying to set up a new WLAN. Cisco 5508 controller. W2K8R2 for DHCP.
Why would VLAN 600 not appear as active in management domain?

I have an AP (Aironet 1041) assigned to VLAN 600. I am unable to pull a DHCP address over WiFi, although it works fine over ethernet.

The AP is connected to a switch, trunked to another switch, trunked to the 5508. All VLANs are allowed on all trunks.

[Pastebin link to WAC config](http://pastebin.com/w9Jtq6xX)

On the switch connected to the AP:

```
Port        Vlans allowed on trunk  
Gi0/16      1-4094  
Gi0/23      1-4094  
Port        Vlans allowed and active in management domain  
Gi0/16      1,20,80,100,500  
Gi0/23      1,20,80,100,500
```

`Gi0/16` is connected to the AP. `Gi0/23` is the trunk port to the next switch.

Switchport config for AP device:

```
S03#sh int g0/16 switchport  
Name: Gi0/16  
Switchport: Enabled  
Administrative Mode: trunk  
Operational Mode: trunk  
Administrative Trunking Encapsulation: dot1q  
Operational Trunking Encapsulation: dot1q  
Negotiation of Trunking: Off  
Access Mode VLAN: 1 (default)  
Trunking Native Mode VLAN: 1 (default)  
Administrative Native VLAN tagging: enabled  
Voice VLAN: none  
Administrative private-vlan host-association: none  
Administrative private-vlan mapping: none  
Administrative private-vlan trunk native VLAN: none  
Administrative private-vlan trunk Native VLAN tagging: enabled  
Administrative private-vlan trunk encapsulation: dot1q  
Administrative private-vlan trunk normal VLANs: none  
Administrative private-vlan trunk associations: none  
Administrative private-vlan trunk mappings: none  
Operational private-vlan: none  
Trunking VLANs Enabled: ALL  
Pruning VLANs Enabled: 2-1001  
Capture Mode Disabled  
Capture VLANs Allowed: ALL
```

Comment: @YLearn that was it. Troubleshooting the wrong things. Careless. Thank you. If you make it an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the output of *show vlan*.

When a VLAN doesn't show up as active in the management domain, it will almost always be because the VLAN doesn't exist on the switch.

The switch may have a configuration problem with VTP or it may be configured to operate in transparent mode.

Answer (score 0):

i am new to this blog.
I maybe wrong, but if "show vlan brief says 1-4094 are allowed", which includes your vlan 600.
Since Aironet(AP) is connected to Switchport Gi0/16. It should be an Access Port, and Enabling PortFast on that, would get the IP from DHCP.
And one more thing, S03#sh int g0/16 switchport
it shows "Operational Mode: trunk", when it should show Static(Access Port).
You said, all vlans are allowed on "all Trunks".

I could be wrong, but that might solve the issue.

Comment: Note the date of the question (2014) and the accepted answer (also 2014.)  The original poster had neglected to create VLAN 600 on the affected device, as indicated by the accepted answer.  The alternate answer you've supplied is actually incorrect.